# set attribute value of class object from result of database query

Tags: python, postgresql

I want to set attribute value for object of class in python from query database, but I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/s2/semester 3/tesis/phyton/connectDatabase", line 27, in <module>
data.append(Spatial_object(row[i]))
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)
```

This is my code:

```
class Spatial_object:
    def __init__(self, jenis,Lat,Long):
        self.jenis=jenis
        self.Lat=Lat
        self.Long=Long

cur.execute("""SELECT primary_descript,lat,long from data_crime""")
row = cur.fetchall() 

data = []
for i in range(0,rows_effected):
    data.append(Spatial_object(row[i]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `primary_descript` maps to `jenis` then you need to pass that and the lat and long that you retrieve from the database (once that part of your code is working juga :)) when instantiating the `Spatial_object` object.

This is because the `__init__()` method of class `Spatial_object` requires 4 arguments: `self`, `jenis`, `Lat`, and `Long` to match the declaration:

```
def __init__(self, jenis,Lat,Long):
```

`self`, which is a reference to the instance of the object itself, is passed automatically.

The second part of your code doesn't look like it will work, e.g. what is `rows_effected`? Anyway, you don't need to know how many rows were returned, you can iterate over the rows with something like this:

```
cur.execute("""SELECT primary_descript,lat,long from data_crime""")

data = []
for jenis, lat, lon in cur.fetchall():
    data.append(Spatial_object(jenis, lat, lon))
```

You could even simplify the code further with a list comprehension:

```
data = [Spatial_object(jenis, lat, lon) for jenis, lat, lon in cur.fetchall()]
```

or a less readable version:

```
data = [Spatial_object(*row) for row in cur.fetchall()]
```

Finally, your class would be better named `Spatial` than `Spatial_object`.

Comment: Thank you, it's fix. I use your code:
cur.execute("""SELECT primary_descript,lat,long from data_crime""")

data = []
for jenis, lat, lon in cur.fetchall():
    data.append(Spatial_object(jenis, lat, lon))

Answer (score 2):

Python tells exactly what the problem is - the `Spatial_object.__init__()` method expects three explicit arguments: `jenis`, `Lat` and `Lon`, while you supply only one in `Spastial_object(row[i])`. Try destructing the row into a list of arguments, i.e.: `Spatial_object(*row[i])`.